# Calculating $E[X^2Y^2]$ given $E[X^2]$, $E[Y^2]$, $E[X]$, $E[Y]$, and that $X$, $Y$ are Gaussian.

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose $E[X]=E[Y]=0$, and $E[X^2]=E[Y^2]=1$.  Can you show that $E[X^2Y^2] = 1 + 2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)^2$?  I am not even sure if this expression is correct, I found it in a geostatistics paper, which used this result to show something else.  (Note that under these conditions $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$ is simply equal to $E[XY]$).

edit: $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian random variables.  Also, it might possibly be useful to consider $E[E[X^2Y^2|X]]$.

Comment: Hmm... the variables $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian, although I can't see this helping...

Comment: Doesn't look like it.  Suppose
$$
X = \begin{cases} 1/\sqrt{2} & \text{with probability } 1/2, \\ -1/\sqrt{2} & \text{with probability } 1/2. \end{cases}
$$
And $Y$ has the same distribution and is independent of $X$.  Then $E(X^2 Y^2) = 1/4$ and $1 + 2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)^2 = 1$.

Comment: You should really edit the information that the variables are gaussian into the question. Gaussians are far more constrained than general random variables. That said, I suspect this will wind up closed as too elementary; you'd probably do better on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the example Michael.  I edited the question to add more conditions.

Comment: I consider this to be an exercise. The point is that it can all be worked out with explicit formulas. 

Comment: I do not condiser myself as experienced enough on this site to simply do a roll-back. But I find this edit unfortunate.

Comment: It's not a very polite thing to completely erase your question, especially if there are answers posted. Remember this site is here to help everybody who might encounter similar questions, not just you. I made a roll-back.

Comment: From an ongiong conversation with the questioner on another question, I have the strong impression that this was done with good intentions (a misconception of the etiquette here).

Comment: Thanks unknown.  Yes, it was a mistake.  And thanks Gjergji for the roll-back.

Comment: actually I have a great answer to that question that could help many people (considering the amount of people watching that question). It uses Isserlis Theorem, and allows to generalize the question. I'm editing the question and posting the idea : when you have 4 real valued gaussian random variables with zero means : $$ E( X_j X_k X_l X_m) = E(X_j X_k ) E(X_l X_m )+ E(X_j X_l )E(X_k X_m )+ E(X_j X_m )E(X_k X_l ) $$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result holds if, additionnally to the conditions of the post, one assumes that the **vector** $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian. Then, $Y=aX+\sqrt{1-a^2}Z$ with $a=\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)$ and $Z$ standard Gaussian such that $X$ and $Z$ are independent. Using $E(X^4)=3$, $E(Z)=0$, $E(X^2)=E(Z^2)=1$ and the independence of $X$ and $Z$, one gets indeed that $E(X^2Y^2)=3a^2+0+1-a^2=1+2a^2$.

Otherwise, that is, under the conditions of the post only, the result is false. For example, if $Y=UX$ with $U=\pm1$ centered and such that $U$ and $X$ are independent. all the hypotheses of the post are met but $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)=0$ and $E(X^2Y^2)=3$.

A well known motto in such situations is: "Joint laws, or else..."

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.  In the paper I am reading, it does hold that vector (X,Y) is Gaussian, so that was a hidden assumption in my question.  